# django does not change the login page

Tags: django, postgresql

I changed the database drastically with django.
Then we migrated and confirmed that the table was created.
If you try to log in to the management screen as a superuser after starting the server, the screen will not change.
It reacts when the wrong password is entered.

The server was restarted and postgre was also reinstalled.
But it does not change.
It will look like you've been waiting for a long time.

If you put the wrong one, it will respond “Please enter the correct username and password”.
You can transition to a screen that does not require login.

Comment: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL is set?
Can you confirm in database sessions if a session was created for the user?
is there any error on django log?

Comment: When migrating, the user's session could not be migrated. The problem was that makemigrations left the previous data.
I was saved.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Did you make sure to `collectstatic`, and did you restart the web service?